# How to make a helper function which manipulates an instance?

Tags: php

I am busy learning as much as I can about php frameworks.

At the moment I have a file full of routes. The routes take this general form.

```
$bootstrap->router->add('/home', ['controller' => 'home', 'action' => 'index']);
```

So, the 'routes' file is not a class, it is just a file which I include into the index.php page just underneath `$bootstrap = new Bootstrap($router);`.

As you can see, to add a route I add it to the instantiated **$bootstrap** object, which itself has an instantiated **->router** object inside which I am calling the **'add()'** method.

Now I want to make it easier to add routes by writing something like this...

```
route('/home', ['controller' => 'home', 'action' => 'index']);
```

**question**

Exactly how to go about this is unclear... I am not even sure if this is a done thing. I have tried making a 'helpers/RoutesHelper file' but that takes my request out of the object scope...

...so I am a bit confused, how do I go about implementing a plane old helper function inside object oriented code?

Many thanks in advance.

Comment: um... put in a function named route maybe?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

### anonymous function

If you are willing to add a `$` to the beginning of that `route(...` line:

```
$route = function($path, $options) use ($bootstrap) {
     $bootstrap->router->add($path, $options);
}
```

would work.

### global `$bootstrap`

Otherwise it would be dirty to bring the bootstrap object into the route function:

```
function route($path, $options) {
     global $bootstrap; // <-- i don't like this
     $bootstrap->router->add($path, $options);
}
```

### definitions in array

you could also just make an array in your file like:

```
$routes = array()
$routes['/home'] = ['controller' => 'home', 'action' => 'index'];
// ... more routes ...
```

and in your main program just loop over that array:

```
foreach($routes as $path => $options) {
    $bootstrap->router->add($path, $options);
}
```

those are the three solutions that pop into my mind ...

Comment: Very interesting, thank you so much for showing the different methods of doing this, such interesting stuff!

Comment: personally, I'd prefer the "definitions in array" version. ;o)

Comment: Great solution to the issue... looks much cleaner, it's going to take a while to digest all this great info!

Answer (score 1):

Like this

```
if(!function_exists( 'route' ) ){
    function route( $path, $params ){
        $bootstrap = ''; //?
        $bootstrap->router->add($path, $params);
    }
}
```

Of course I have no idea where $bootstrap came from, so you'll want that in there, obviously.  You could pass that in as a parameter, but it would be better to initialize it inside the function if possible.

Comment: you may want to do `}else{` and error check for if the function exists, but that depends on your framework.

Comment: Thanks, will take that into consideration.